# How to make a working search form PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, laravel, search

So basically I'm doing a project for college and the only thing missing from my project is a working search form, but i don't know how to do it. All of my products are created and seeded into the database.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'ProductsController@getIndex',
    'as'=> 'product.index'
 ] //tenho de meter um . porque nao é uma diretoria global, index ta dentro 
duma pasta shop
 );
```

my table:

```
  Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string("imagePath");
        $table->string("title");
        $table->text("description");
        $table->integer("price");
    });
```

my form structure:

```
   <form action="" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left " role = "search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </form>
```

my products controller:

```
   public function getIndex(){
    $products = Products::all();
    return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to do one but i cant seem to make it filter the ones i have, for example, if i have 3 boots and 5 shoes on the shop, if i write "boot" on the search, i want only for the 3 boots to appear

Comment: have you created a search route

Comment: yes i did, Route::post('/', [
    'uses' => 'ProductsController@searchProducts',
    'as'=>'product.search'
]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your HTML would be

```
<form action="{{ route('product.search') }}" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left " role = "search">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

in your `searchProduct` function

for like query where it can search in title and if keyword present it will return all product who has same title you are searching for

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request){
    $products = Product::where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
    return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

for exact same title result

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request){
    $products = Product::where('title',$request->search)->get();
    return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Comment: it doesnt give me any errors, but it shows the shop.index page with any filters of what i put inside the search box. All my products still show up

Comment: do you have boots in your all product title field

Comment: It didnt work because i have 2 names in my form (name= "search" and name = "keyword" )

Answer (score 0):

there are a LOT of different ways to approach something like a search ... ranging from simple to very complex but a basic method would to search your title and description fields for a keyword like "boot".

You'll want to add a couple of things ...
First, add a new route to handle the search request:

```
Route::post('/results', [
  'uses' => 'ProductsController@searchProducts', 
  'as'=>'product.search'
]);
```

Next, add a name to your html input, such as 'keyword' along with the blade shortcut for the CSRF token field:

```
<form action="/results" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left " role = "search">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="keyword">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then add a function to your controller to handle the query:

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request){
  $results = Product::where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orderBy('title', 'desc')
    ->get();

  return view('search_results', ['results'=>$results, 'keyword'=>$request->keyword]);
}
```

Finally, create a new file named search_results.blade.php and place it in your views directory.  This will be used to display the search results to the user.

```
<h2>Search Results for {{$keyword}}</h4>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($results as $result)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$result->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$result->description}}</td>
                <td>{{$result->price}}</td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    No Products Found
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With this foundation, you could really go wild and add filtering options, sorting, ranking and more.  Hope that helps get you going!

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping. Second, i get the error "419 : Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again." Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, sorry ... Laravel has built functions to protect against cross site request forgery (CSRF).  Any time you submit a form, it checks to see if a special token was added to the request ... so you need to include that.  Easiest way is to simply add @csrf somewhere within the form.  Basically, that's just a blade shortcut that adds a hidden form input with the token.  No other changes should be required.

Comment: but its {{csrf_token}} or {{csrf_field}} ? And i add it right next to the </form> ?

Comment: Laravel gives you a few ways to do this, but from within a blade template (view) you can use the shortcut @csrf.  Technically you can place that anywhere within your form tags, but I generally add it right at the top.  I updated my answer to include the token.  {{csrf_field()}} works too ... same output, different syntax.

Comment: FYI: csrf_token() will give you just the token value.  csrf_field() will give you the complete form field with the token filled in.

Comment: I put it at the end before you answered and it seemed to have the same use. Now it was that"View [search_results] not found.". And i should replace it with "shop.index" or "/" to go to the main page but with the listed items. But if i do that it gives me an error of a file i didnt even touch for this problem.

Comment: In my example, you'll want to create a new view file named search_results.blade.php to display the results on.  You could also reuse the same view by adding a check to see if the $results variable set and conditionally showing the results section.  Lots of different options depending on how you want the search to work.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

```
html

       <form action="/search" method='post' class="navbar-form navbar-left " role = "search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>


    PHP

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $products = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.request->search.'%')->get();

        return view('search', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

Only change wich view you want return and create too in to a routes/web.php.